# NoMethodError for underscore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to convert the string

```
"Full Time"
```

to

```
"full_time"
```

When I using "Full Time".underscore in irb, it prompt a error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `underscore' for "Full Time":String
```

How can I fix it? Or is there any other way for me to get the above underscored result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a rails helper method called underscore. If you fire your rails console (script/console) you will be able to use it:

```
"FullTime".gsub(/\s+/,'').underscore.to_sym
:full_time
```

so what i think that you should do is, remove space and then apply the method described above. Note that I added to_sym just to show that it is possible as well, but if you don't need it, just remove it.

*Note that it is a rails helper and not a ruby method from the String class. It will just works in the rails enviornment*.

Comment: oooo i forgot this is a rails helper but i tested it in irb -_-||

thanks for reminding me buddy. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use gsub and replace all whitespaces to underscore

```
irb(main):008:0> "Full Time".downcase.gsub(/\s+/,"_")
=> "full_time"
```